# continuing outer loop of asyncio python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, telethon

I want to continue my outer loop but in async function it looks like, when the task completed program will stop.
this is piece of my code
I want to do something in main every 50 seconds and then call blabla

```
async def blabla():
 
    await client.send_message()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        scrap_time = datetime.now()
    
        print(scrap_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "scraping started ...")
 
        asyncio.run(blabla())
        time.sleep(50)
```

And finally this will be shown in console

```
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: What happens after 50 seconds?

Comment: it is in while true loop so the cursor goes to "scrap_time ... " and then againg asyncio.run(blabla()) and again sleeps 50 seconds

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: the problem is blabla will run but time.sleep() wont so while true wont continue

Comment: You just wrote that it again sleeps 50 seconds, so time.sleep() does run. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I trace it at debug mode and breakpoint did not reach :(

Comment: When you're debugging did you wait for 50 seconds? Try decreasing the time to 1 second.

Comment: I did it , nothing matters!
finally the code will exit with this message
Process finished with exit code -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve here since your code seems to perform the desired functionality you described of "I want to do something in main every 50 seconds and then call blabla" albeit in a slightly odd manner.

I've refactored this to do exactly what you described of "do something in main every 50 seconds and then call blabla". The sleep is asynchronous so you do not block the main python process with the blocking `time.sleep()` call.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def blabla():
    await client.send_message()

async def main():
    print("doing something in main...")
    scrap_time = datetime.now()
    print(scrap_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "scraping started ...")        

async def run():
    """
    every 50 seconds, do something in main() and then call blabla()
    """
    while True:
        await main()
        await blabla()
        await asyncio.sleep(50)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run())
```

Functionally this is equivalent to your program but, as I said, from your description it seems that your program already achieves the desired outcome. When debugging you may want to decrease the sleep value from 50 seconds to 1 second so you don't have to wait so long for the rest of the program to resume.